# How to specify table name with Entity Framework Code First Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have an Entity and I am to configure Entity Framework to map it to a database table with different name.

I can easily do this with **[Code First DataAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations)** (**DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute**).

But due to limitations now I have to use **[Code First Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)** (my domain objects will be used by external clients, so they shouldn't be technology-specific - e.g. have any references to DataAnnotations)

I've searched on MSDN but found nothing. So is it possible and how?

Thank you.

Comment: In general you should create DTO's (data transfer objects) and map your EF objects to them, you should never use the EF classes directly unless you're working on a small/trivial app.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You'll use the `.ToTable()` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("t_Department");
```

Source: MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

Comment: i prefer this because i want all anotations in one place

Comment: it there any validation that the table exists?  we renamed a table and nothing broke, is this the behavior you'd expect?  it obviously can't do CRUD on the renamed table, but it doesn't seem to break anything...

Answer (score 244):

You can also use the Table annotation:

```
[Table("InternalBlogs")]
public class Blog
```

See: 
[Code First Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn)

Comment: Thx, but if you carefully read my question - you'll see that apptoach directly in the middle of it :)

Comment: Even though the annotation is named "Table", it appears to work fine for views as well as for tables.

Comment: @JonSchneider I'm just arguing definitions here for no reason in particular, but a view is a read-only table.

Comment: The Table annotation resides in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;.

Comment: How has this got more upvotes, the question clearly asks for the fluent api version

Answer (score 11):

Use ToTable method:

```
public class MyEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public const string TableName = "MyEntity";

    public MyEntityMap()
    {                   
        ToTable(TableName);

        Property(t => t.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think breaking out your mappings into classes is the cleanest approach.

Comment: But then in your `OnModelCreating` method you have to do: `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyEntityMap());` where instead of you could have just added a `modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyEntityTable");` so no, this is not the cleaner way unless you also had other mapping to do for this entity.