# Invalid object name exception refers to an object that I haven't created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently, I am trying to pull information from a database using the EntityFramework. As such, I have connected to the proper database:

```
<add name="ChartConn" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;Password=****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

where the asterisks are filled in with the correct personal information for that database.

The issue is when I attempt to pull information from this database with the following in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var q = (from c in db.ChannelMaps
            select c.LABEL).ToList();

    return View(q);
}
```

and the following in the model, CHANNELMAP:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ChartApp.Models
{
    public class CHANNELMAP
    {
        [Key]
        public int CHANNELNUM { get; set; }
        public int COLUMNID { get; set; }
        public string LABEL { get; set; }
        public string RAWUNITS { get; set; }
        public double? MULT { get; set; }
        public double? ADDER { get; set; }
        public int? DATATYPEID { get; set; }
        public int? OPCODEID { get; set; }
        public decimal? OPVALUE { get; set; }
        public int? SITEID { get; set; }
        public string DASNAME { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChannelMapContext : DbContext
    {
        public ChannelMapContext()
            : base("ChartConn")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Models.ChannelMapContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<CHANNELMAP> ChannelMaps { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I get an error: Invalid object name `dbo.CHANNELMAPs`, that points to the first line (`from c in db.ChannelMaps`) of my linq query in my controller. This is strange because my model's name is CHANNELMAP, so I am unsure as to why I am getting an error for an invalid name for an object that I have not used. What is causing this error? I have tried changing the name of my model numerous times, as well as triple-checking to make sure my connection string and property names are all set up accordingly.

Comment: What DB structure do you have?

Comment: Pretty sure that `public DbSet<CHANNELMAP> ChannelMaps { get; set; }` should be `public DbSet<CHANNELMAP> CHANNELMAPs { get; set; }` in your `ChannelMapContext` class. I believe (if I remember right) that it takes the type name and appends a pluralizer to it for mapping.

Comment: I tried changing around how I declared the DBSet variable, but it ended up not making a difference. The selected answer fixed everything without needing to change my DBSet variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default EF adds an 's' (pluralization) at the end of each entities in the model. To remove that you just remove that convention:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
 }
```

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object
>   name 'dbo.CHANNELMAPs'

This error means that EF is translating your LINQ into a sql statement that uses a table, which does not exist in the database.

Check your database and verify whether that table exists, or that you should be using a different table name.

Comment: Both of these answers fix the problem completely, but I will choose this one because it gives a better idea of what is going on behind the scenes. Thanks for the help! I was tearing my hair out for two hours trying to debug this, and the fix ended up being so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework assumes by convention that table names are pluralized versions of the entity name (hence the error message reference to `CHANNELMAPs`). If your entity is in fact called `CHANNELMAP`, add the `Table` attribute to it.

```
[Table("CHANNELMAP")]
public class CHANNELMAP
    { ...
```

see this for more info: [Howto specify table name with Entity Framework Code First Fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184644/howto-specify-table-name-with-entity-framework-code-first-fluen-api)