# Entity Framework 6 Migrations - Generates "SchemaName"."TableName"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on a database for maritime monitoring data. I made a classic EER-Model (MySQL Workbench), generated an interim database for Entity Framework 6 Code First by Database First to get started with Entity classes and DbContext implementation. From here on out **I need to use EF Migrations**
When I **add** the **initial Migration** the create table statements are naming the Tables like **"DbContext"."TableName"**so the Database looks like **"SchemaName"."DbContext"."TableName"** which is ugly AF.

I could write table names in modelbuilder fluentAPI or annotate them, but this is a hassle with a huge number of tables.

how can I alter the conventional naming? I just want the migrator to **call the table like the property in DbContext derived class**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto specify table name with Entity Framework Code First Fluent API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184644/howto-specify-table-name-with-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the Table annotation:

```
[Table("InternalBlogs")]
public class Blog
```

See: [Code First Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn)

Comment: thank you Zaheer. Your comment pointed me to the right thing. The code first database first thing annotaded all classes with the schema name in front (which I didn't check for some reason)