# SQLite Error 1: no such table in ASP.Net Core Console App

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console-application, asp.net-core-2.0

I've followed the instructions on how to wire this up using the docs provided by MS. However, I am not having any success getting the data from the database.

The error I am receiving is this:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: ModelRecords'.
```

I setup the DBContext like so:

```
public class SsimDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string db_file = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DocumentUpdaterDbLocation");
        Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(db_file) ? $"Database found at {db_file}" : $"Could not find database at {db_file}");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={db_file}");
    }

    public DbSet<ST_Record> ModelRecords { get; set; }
}
```

The difference here is that I get path to the database from an environmental variable. When I write this variable to the console, it shows the path that I am expecting to the database:

`Database found at C:\develop\temp\LFReview\sdb\MasterSdb.sdb`

The ST_Record table is defined as:

```
public class ST_Record
{
    [Key]
    public int ST_RecordID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Running this query in the database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ST_Record;
```

Returns:

```
COUNT(*)
1808
```

Finally, the error is thrown here:

```
List<ST_Record> stt = _context.ModelRecords.Select(r => r).ToList();
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Your naming is off if your table is named ST_Record. EF is not going to help with that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184644/howto-specify-table-name-with-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api

Answer (score 2):

I meet this problem today and the db file sometimes will not generated in your bin folder , so you will get a  error like this
`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table:` 
you can try to solve this by copying your db file from your project folder to your bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line Just below the TargetFramework property of the .csproj file.

```
<StartWorkingDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</StartWorkingDirectory>
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=visual-studio